# Is it possible to set "start_pitch" for VR View for the Web

Tags: google-vr, 360-panorama

The documentation for Google's VR View on the Web has the "start_yaw" control parameter which allows one to rotate the starting orientation of the image horizontally:

> start_yaw: {Number} Initial yaw of viewer, in degrees. (optional, default 0)

Is it possible to set the starting pitch (vertical rotation) as well?

Adding "start_pitch=90" has no effect.

https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web

Comment: In the documentation there is not such a parameter...